# Userscript. Удалить iFrame из родителя

Tags: javascript, userjs, iframe

Всем доброго времени суток. 
Попытки удалить вызванный мной **iFrame** из **userscript**, к сожалению, ни к чему не привели. Я разбит и деморализован ) Прошу совета, а еще лучше готовый пример )

Ситуация следующая.
Идут часы, под интервалом (***setInterval***) одна минута. В определённое время, запускается iFrame и он делает свое дело… а таймер дальше себе работает.

```
setInterval(function(){
    setHTime();

    if(myTimer.innerHTML == "22:00:00"){
          iFaremes(0);
          //delIFr(0);
     }                        
},1000);
```

У меня есть функция, которая отлично удаляет этот iFrame из основного окна.

```
function delIFr(arg){
      console.log("удаляем Frame");
      var frame = document.getElementById("ifrid"+arg);
      frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
}
```

Я пытался вызвать её из открытого iFrame:

```
if (w.self != w.top) {
       if (w.name = "ifrname0") {
           //много нужного кода
           window.parent.delIFr(0);
        }else{
            return;
        }
    }
```

***ERROR***: *Execution of script 'HA3IK' failed! Object [object global] has no method 'delIFr'*

Посоветуйте, как мне можно вызвать эту функцию (*delIFr*) в основном окне, через вызванный **iFrame**.

Comment: Весело наверно код путем копировать вставить писать :)  

    window.top.dellFr();

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/T2jzz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот эта демка должна внести ясность в вопрос, если непонятно чего - спрашивайте.

```
function createframes(n) {
    for (var i=0;i<n;i++) {
        var frame=document.createElement('iframe');
        document.body.appendChild(frame);
        frame.contentWindow.myFrameInParent=frame; //положить в переменную внутри iframe ссылку на него самого в родителе
        frame.contentWindow.delIFr=delIFr; //положить ссылку на функцию delIfr 
        var script = frame.contentWindow.document.createElement('script'); //эти три строки просто чтобы загнать скрипт в iframe
        script.innerHTML = 'setTimeout(function(){delIFr(myFrameInParent);},'+1000*(i+1)+')';
        frame.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);        
    }

}

function delIFr(frame) {
    console.log("удаляем Frame ");
    frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);    
}
createframes(5);
delIFr(document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]); //можно и отсюда удалить
```

Comment: Блин, похоже Я жестко ступил с аргументом для функции delIFr. Большое спасибо за пример и идею с внедрением скрипта с таймером.